# contour integral and existence of the antiderivate

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Integrate this.

$\int_{\vert z \vert =1}(1-{1 \over {z^2}}) e^{z+  {1 \over z}} $  for $f(z) = (1-{1 \over {z^2}}) e^{z+  {1 \over z}}$

---

First) My colleague claim that for the closed curve $\vert z \vert =1$ and exists antiderivative of $f(z)$, Hence answer is $0$. But I'm not sure why does have a antiderivative.

Second) Plus, Are there any determine method for the existence of the antiderivative by intuitively method?

e.g.) Like the thought that antiderivative of $g(z)$ = $1 \over z$ multi-valued function it doesn't have a unique antiderivate So we can't say that there is a antiderivate of the $g(z)$. But this thought just only applied for the $1 \over z$ not applied the case $f(z)$ etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By inspection $f(z)$ is derivative of $e^{z+\frac  1 z}$. Hence the integral is $0$.

Existence of anti-derivative is not always obvious.  No general procedure can be prescribed.